# OutputStream with ByteArrayOutputStream writing partly then stopping

Tags: java, file

so i am trying to write some ints on a file per 1000 ints using a byte Array but it only does it one time(i have confirmed it using a hexeditor) when i would like about 1000 and i have no idea why it actually does the first but then stops.these are the errors that come up: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) at test.Class1.main(Class1.java:32)**

```
 public class Class1 {



    static byte[] buf=new byte[1000];

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            ByteArrayOutputStream BOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
            DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(BOS);

            RandomAccessFile MyFile = new RandomAccessFile ("myfile.dat", "rw");
            int acc=0;

            int k=0;
            for( k=0;k<100;k++) {

                buf=bufferFiller( buf);         
                DOS.write(buf, k*1000, buf.length); 
                acc++;
            }

        }           
        public static byte[] bufferFiller(byte[] buf) {
            int i=0;
            int  randomNum=0;
            for(i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                buf[i]=(byte) (randomNum = -50000 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100000) + 1)));
            }
            return buf;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so the offset is for the buffer,not the file ? yes it is ,thanks a lot so in similar case if i want to use read(byte[], int off, len) i also put 0 everytime ?

Comment: OK, I read again. Yes, it should be the offset in the buffer. [DataOutputStream.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-): "Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to the underlying output stream."

Comment: Yes, a `read` will read `len` bytes into the specified `byte[]` array, and place those bytes starting at the `off`, so generally use 0.

Comment: so the only way to get offset off file is the seek function? for example i want to read 1000nth through  2000nth number i will have to first seek(1000) then myFile.read(b[]) and your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, I suppose with a small enough file you could read the whole thing into a buffer, but yes in general you'd need to seek to the correct location in the file and then read the desired number of bytes.

Comment: god bless you man ,i might actually finish on time :) is there any way that i can upvote you or something?

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: i upvoted but not enough rep to make a difference

Comment: Hi, you can accept the answer, if it solved your issue. I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's question, the issue was with the use of the offset in the buffer.

[Javadoc for DataOutputStream.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-) (emphasis added)

> public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
>
> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array *starting at offset off* to the underlying output stream. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by len.

So, the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` was a result of this line:

```
DOS.write(buf, k*1000, buf.length);
```

By always using a "0" for the offset, the `.write(...)` will write the number of bytes (in this case the length of the buf), *starting* from the offset (which should be 0). The OP was nicely always re-filling the buffer in each loop iteration.

So changing to something like:

```
for( k=0;k<100;k++) {
  buf=bufferFiller( buf);         
  DOS.write(buf, 0, buf.length); 
  acc++;
}
```

should resolve the issue.